# Collect External Output (echo) and Save as a Variable for Testing

Tags: bash, if-statement, logic, echo, submit

I have a command that should fail and output a specific echo.

IF the user submits:

```
./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat
```

THEN

1. The script should fail
2. Echo `"Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human"`.

I am trying to save this echo in a variable in order to run a simple test case.
Basically:
WHEN the user runs the script containing the test case (see my strategies below)

```
./test_script.sh
```

THEN they receive an echo back stating: `"Unrecognized argument test case: pass"`

My strategies (I've tried these and every small variation I can think of):

**1)** **Input:** **test_script.sh contains "echo" when saving the output of  the submit_script.sh file into a variable.**

**Output:** **nothing is echoed when ./test_script.sh is run**

```html
bat_input=$(echo ./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat)   

if [[ "$bat_input" =~ "Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human" ]]; then                                         
    echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"                    
fi
```

**2)** **Input:** **test_script.sh does not include echo when saving the output of  the submit_script.sh file into a variable**

**Output:** **Echo `"Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human"` (not the right echo, expecting "Unrecognized argument test case: pass")**

```html
bat_input=$(./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat)   

if [[ "$bat_input" =~ "Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human" ]]; then                                         
    echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"                    
fi
```

**3)** ****Input:** test_script.sh includes ">/dev/null 2>&1" when saving the output of  the submit_script.sh file into a variable**

**Output:** **nothing is echoed when ./test_script.sh is run**

```html
bat_input=$(./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat >/dev/null 2>&1)  

if [[ "$bat_input" =~ "Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human" ]]; then                                         
    echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"                    
fi
```

**4)** **Input:** **test_script.sh removes the quotations around the bat_input variable in the if statement**

**Output:** **Echo `"Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human"` (not the right echo, expecting "Unrecognized argument test case: pass")**

```html
bat_input=$(./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat)   

if [[ $bat_input =~ "Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human" ]]; then                                         
    echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"                    
fi
```

**5)** ****Input:** **test_script.sh adds *'s to the regex command in the if statement****

**Output:** **Echo `"Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human"` (not the right echo, expecting "Unrecognized argument test case: pass")**

```html
bat_input=$(./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat)   

if [[ "$bat_input" =~ *"Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human"* ]]; then                                         
    echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"                    
fi
```

In all of these cases, there is no output aside from the "Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human" echo, which I would ideally like to suppress. I don't understand why these if statements aren't triggering an echo stating ""Unrecognized argument test case: pass". Ideas? Let me know if I need to make any clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
bat_input=$(./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat)   

if [[ "$bat_input" =~ "Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human" ]]; then                                         
    echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"                    
fi
```

```html
bat_input=$(./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat)   

if [[ $bat_input =~ "Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human" ]]; then                                         
    echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"                    
fi
```

Comment: How are those solutions different than #2 and #4 I gave above (sorry if I am missing something stupid)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am pretty sure solving my question is not possible because of how bash handles strings. Ie the echo output is `Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human` not `"Unrecognized argument. Possible arguments: cat, dog, human"`.

What I ended up doing is using the exit 1 status as a proxy. Ie:

```html
bat_input=$(./submit_script.sh path/1/to/file1 path/2/to/file2 --bat)   
    if [[ $bat_input -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "Unrecognized argument test case: pass"
    fi
```

This isn't great because an exit 1 error code can occur for many reasons, but it's all I have been able to come up with.

Is my issue in fact due to how bash handles strings? Or am I missing something else?